# How can I prevent ZygoteInit Exception?

Tags: android

I got an Exception report from my app in Google Play:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dominionmobile.android.weather.l.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is a nearly identical Exception reported in this forum entry:
[What are ZygoteInit calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932630/what-are-zygoteinit-calls)

I can't reproduce the problem, but going off that forum entry, it looks like they
are launching the app, doing something, then doing a back, putting the app
in the background, then launching it again.

So my question is, what kind of preventive code can I add to help avoid this issue?
I'm assuming it's all happening in my Main Activity.

I do have some OnClickListeners that I'm not setting to null on onStop(),
and I don't think I need to try to preserve any state of the app on re-entry,
it gets what it needs from it's database and from SharedPreferences when it starts up.

I think I've seen this same Exception before, from the Exception Reports, but it rarely happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an NPE when calling handle message. See the first lines of the log. If you kept your mapping.txt file you can symbolicate to get readable information from the report.

Comment: I saw that, but I wasn't sure it was related to it.  Should be easy to fix then, Thanks!