# java.lang.NullPointerException: at com.google.firebase.iid.zzad.zzchp

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Below error is reported by Play Store. android vitals.

I am using 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run (LoadedApk.java:1195)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzad.zzchp (zzad.java)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzae.onReceive (zzae.java)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run (LoadedApk.java:1185)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Any clue please ?

Comment: Any more details please? I do not expect a compile action to run into a NullPointerException

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932630/what-are-zygoteinit-calls

Answer (score 2):

> Cloud Messaging
>
> **CHANGED:** FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver has been removed from the SDK's automatically-merged AndroidManifest. If you weren't using
>   Gradle or its manifest automerging feature and were adding this
>   receiver manually, you can now remove it.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

It's just a crash caused by a vestige from FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver during apk update. The receiver still functioning, but the class is gone and then... crashes.